# Comparator class implementation for priority queue used in Dijkstra's Algorithm?

Tags: java, collections, priority-queue, comparator, comparable

I'm trying to implement Dijsktra's Algorithm from CLRS - Introduction to Algorithms book,however, i'm having trouble about implementing a priority queue with `Comparator` interface. This is my Vertex class as you can see;

```
public class Vertex {

    public boolean explored;
    public int vertexID;
    public LinkedList<Vertex> adjacencyList;
    public LinkedList<Edge> edgeSet;
    public int shortestDistance;
    public Vertex predecessor;

    public Vertex(int vertexID){

        this.vertexID = vertexID;
        this.explored = false;
        this.adjacencyList = new LinkedList<>();
        this.edgeSet = new LinkedList<>();
        this.shortestDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        this.predecessor = null;
    }
}
```

So initially `shortestDistance` attribute is declared to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Furthermore, you can see the class which implements from Comparator, is used for priority queue.

```
public class WeightComparator implements Comparator<Vertex> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Vertex o1, Vertex o2) {

        return Math.min(o1.shortestDistance, o2.shortestDistance);
    }
}
```

I'm sure that the whole implementation doesn't have any logical errors due to my some tests,however, in some tests it fails. I create a reference to my queue with this statement

`PriorityQueue<Vertex> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(N, weightComparator);`

where N is the size of the queue. So please correct me if i'm wrong about the way how it works. When you `poll` an item from it, it will remove the item which has least priority ?. Hope it had been clear to understand my problem, and i will appreciate a lot if anyone can help about this. So thanks anyway

Comment: Your problem is that you're not implementing `Comparator.compare` correctly.  Read the Javadoc for `Comparator`.

Comment: I implemented the `compare` method with 3 three cases which javadoc tells `Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.`, however, it doesnt work properly. The reason might be the range of priorities that there will be thousands of priority ranks instead of -1,0,1 ?

Comment: Is that what you did?  That's not what it looks like from your implementation using `Math.min`.

Comment: question includes my last implementation. As i said in some cases algorithm works well (if i use 3 ranks),however, for some cases it doesnt. Then i decided to use Math.min cause i thought that with Math.min queue could be ordered with proper ranks.

Comment: The result of `Comparator.compare` is not a priority; it distinguishes whether value A has lower, higher, or equal priority compared to value B.

Comment: ok its my fault that i understood the way wrongly about how it works. It is more clear now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Math.min` gives you the smaller of two values. Returning that as a compare value is wrong.

A `compare` return value of <0 means the first value is smaller than the second, but if you return `Math.Min(5, 3)`, you will get 3, which is >0, which means that the comparator will tell it that 3 > 5. Which is wrong.

What you are looking for is:

```
public int compare(Vertex o1, Vertex o2) {
    return Integer.compare(o1.shortestDistance, o2.shortestDistance);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless `shortestDistance` can be negative, your comparator can never return a negative number. It is therefore not a correct implementation.

Conceptually, a comparator for primitives should return a subtraction:

```
return o1.shortestDistance-o2.shortestDistance;
```

or the other way around if you want descending. But you need to beware of overflow issues.

Comment: For a simple subtraction comparator, you need to know for sure that you won't get an overflow.

Comment: so as i understand `compare` method must definitely return a negative number if subtraction is negative ?

Comment: It must definitely return a negative number under the conditions stated in the Javadoc.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus Agreed. Really you need an 'unsigned subtract'. +1 your answer, better than mine.